# Make a div appear in correct position

Tags: jquery, css, css-position

I'm having trouble positioning a div so that it appears in the same place on any resolution/zoom level. When you click this arrow: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPle6.png, I run a jQuery to slide a div down. The problem is that I can't make it appear under that arrow.

Pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g5yAc.png

HTML and Javascript:

```
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script> 
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#flip").click(function() {
                $("#panel").slideToggle(100);
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    Welcome Guest!
    <img src="images/down.png" width="18px" height="18px" alt="Login" id="flip" />

    <div id="panel">
        <form name="login" action="#" method="post">
            Username:<br />
            <input type="text" name="username"><br />
            Password:<br />
            <input type="password" name="password"><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        </form>
    </div>
    ...
```

CSS:

```
#flip  {
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#panel {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 20px;
    right: 0;
    top: 25px;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: left;
}
```

I'm still fairly new to this, so sorry for the bad code. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you need the `position:absolute` on the panel?

Comment: Should that panel be inside another element?

Comment: Thanks for providing the website link. I'll post an answer soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Add `position:relative;` to your div with the id `user`.

Then increase the top value of `panel` to about 50px so it doesnt cover the 'Welcome Guest'.

Now the panels `position:absolute` will be relative to the user div and not to the whole window.

In the end the CSS should look like this:

```
#panel {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    border: 1px solid;
    padding: 20px;
    right: 0;
    top: 50px;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: left;
}
#user {
    position:relative;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You positioned the `#panel` absolutely to the `<body>`, and gave it `right: 0`; so it will appear to the right corner.

You can play with `right: *some magic number*px` or move the `#panel` inside some relativly positioned div:

```
<div id="user">
    <img src="...." />

    <div id="panel">
    .....
    </div>
  </div>

#user{
  position: relative;
}  
#panel {
 right: 0;
 top: 45px;
}
```

Here is the pic. Is that what you need? [image]

Comment: Thank you as well! I saw lukasgeiter's solution first, but yours is basically the same thing. This is exactly what I needed.